# How to get an item from a set of Queues?

Tags: python, multithreading

Say there are two empty `Queue`s. Is there a way to get an item from the queue that gets it first?

So I have a queue of high anonymous proxies, queues of anonymous and transparent ones. Some threads may need only high anon. proxies, while others may accept both high anon. and just anon. proxies. That's why I can't put them all to a single queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had this problem (and "polling", i.e. trying each queue alternately with short timeouts, was unacceptable -- it usually is, being very wasteful of CPU time etc), I would tackle it by designing a "multiqueue" object -- one with multiple condition variables, one per "subqueue" and an overall one.  A put to any subqueue would signal that subqueue's specific condition variable as well as the overall one; a get from a specific subqueue would only wait on its specific condition variable, but there would also be a "get from any subqueue" which waits on the overall condition variable instead.  (If more combinations than "get from this specific subqueue" or "get from any subqueue" need to be supported, just as many condition variables as combinations to support would be needed).

It would be much simpler to code if `get` and `put` were reduced to their bare bones (no timeouts, no no-waits, etc) and all subqueues used a single overall mutex (very small overhead wrt many mutexes, and much easier to code in a deadlock-free way;-).  The subqueues could be exposed as "simplified queue-like duckies" to existing code which assumes it's dealing with a plain old queue (e.g. the multiqueue could support indexing to return proxy objects for the purpose).

With these assumptions, it wouldn't be much code, though it would be exceedingly tricky to write and inspect for correctness (alas, testing is of limited use when very subtle threading code is in play) -- I can't take the time for that right now, though I'd be glad to give it a try tonight (8 hours from now or so) if the assumptions are roughly correct and no other preferable answer has surfaced.

Answer (score 0):

You could check both queues in turn, each time using a short timeout. That way you would most likely read from the first queue that receives data. However, this solution is prone to race conditions if you will be getting many items on a regular basis.

If that is the case, do you have a good reason for not just writing data to one queue?